# Pass argument child type graphql

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-server

I would like to know how can I pass an argument in "child" type.
With the request, I would like to have only the message with id 1 from user id 1.

Currently I have this request :

```
{user(id:1){
  email,
  username,
  messages(id:1){
    text,
    id
  }
}}
```

I modified in the schema the User type, and changed

```
messages: [Message]
```

by

```
messages(id: Int): [Message]
```

But I have always all messages from user and not the message with specific id.

**schema.js**

```
import { gql } from 'apollo-server';

export const typeDefs = gql`

  # declare custom scalars
  scalar Date

  ##########
  ## TYPE ##
  ##########

  # a group
    type Group {
      id: Int!
      name: String
      users: [User]!
      messages: [Message]
    }

  # a user
  type User {
    id: Int! # unique id for the user
    email: String!
    username: String
    messages(id: Int): [Message]
    groups: [Group]
    friends: [User]
  }

  # a message sent from a user to a group
  type Message {
    id: Int!
    to: Group!
    from: User!
    text: String!
    createdAt: Date!
  }

  ###########
  ## QUERY ##
  ###########

  # query for types
  type Query {
    user(email: String, id: Int): User

    messages(groupId: Int, userId: Int): [Message]
  }

  schema {
    query: Query
  }
`;

export default typeDefs;
```

**resolvers.js**

```
import GraphQLDate from 'graphql-date';
import { Group, Message, User } from './connectors';

export const resolvers = {
    Date: GraphQLDate,
    Query: {
        group(_, args) {
            return Group.find({ where: args });
        },
        messages(_, args) {
            return Message.findAll({
                where: args,
                order: [['createdAt', 'DESC']],
            });
        },
        user(_, args) {
            return User.findOne({ where: args });
        },
    },
    Group: {
        users(group) {
            return group.getUsers();
        },
        messages(group) {
            return Message.findAll({
                where: { groupId: group.id },
                order: [['createdAt', 'DESC']],
            });
        },
    },
    Message: {
        to(message) {
            return message.getGroup();
        },
        from(message) {
            return message.getUser();
        },
    },
    User: {
        messages(user) {
            return Message.findAll({
                where: { userId: user.id },
                order: [['createdAt', 'DESC']],
            });
        },
        groups(user) {
            return user.getGroups();
        },
        friends(user) {
            return user.getFriends();
        },
    },
};

export default resolvers;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to update `User.messages` resolver. This way:

```
User: {
        messages(user, { id }) {
            return Message.findAll({
                where: { userId: user.id, id },
                order: [['createdAt', 'DESC']],
            });
        },
        groups(user) {
            return user.getGroups();
        },
        friends(user) {
            return user.getFriends();
        },
    },
```

If you want to make `id` parameter optional, something like this may help:

```
    messages(user, { id }) {
        const where = { userId: user.id }
        if (id) {
          where.id = id
        }

        return Message.findAll({
            where,
            order: [['createdAt', 'DESC']],
        });
    },
```

Comment: What if the nested object type uses boolean arguments instead of integers? Also, is it required for ALL queried types to be listed under type Query, even if I'm supposed to query them only as nested? Will it make much difference if the code is written according to the GraphQL SDL or GraphQLSchema object format?